# Primefaces e Eclipse ctrl + click não funciona

Tags: eclipse, primefaces

Em botões jsf do tipo h:commandButton e h:commandLink a navegação por <kbd>ctrl + click</kbd> funciona perfeitamente.

```
<h:commandButton value="Edit" action="#{bean.edit}"  />
```

Porém quando utilizo as tags do primefaces p:commandButton e p:commandLink a navegação por <kbd>ctrl + click</kbd> não funciona.

```
<p:commandButton value="Edit" action="#{bean.edit}"  />
```

Obs.:
- A navegação por control + click que me refiro é quando presionar o ctrl do teclado e com o a seta do mouse você clica no método e assim é aberto o bean no método específico.

- A versão do Primefaces é a 5

Comment: Creio que isso deveria funcionar, mas isso depende muito da configuração do workspace e do projeto, versão do Eclipse e plugins e da validade do facelet e do projeto como um tudo. Verifique se está tudo certo no projeto, se as dependências estão devidamente no classpath, se o tipo editor usado é o adequado (*Open with*).

Comment: @tuxiron você pode exemplificar o que seria a navegação por Ctrl+Click, e qual a versão do Primefaces?